# How to speed up exporting dataframes to MS SQL Server? R is twice as fast

Tags: pandas, sqlalchemy, bulkinsert, pyodbc, pymssql

I am very well aware that there are many similar questions, and most answers suggest things like bulk inserts of CSVs (which would be more headache than exporting from R).

However, I am not aware of any comparison with R which addresses if `pandas.DataFrame.to_sql()` can ever reach the same speed as R's `DBI::dbWriteTable`.

I run Anaconda on a Windows 10 machine. As a test, I am exporting 15 tables, each with 10,000 rows, 30 columns of random floats and 3 string columns.

The times are:

- pyodbc without fast_executemany : 19 seconds
- pyodbc with fast_executemany : 7 seconds
- turbodbc: 13 seconds
- R and DBI::dbWriteTable : 4    seconds

I tried pymssql but I couln't get it to work (see comments in the code).

`fast_executemany` is a great improvement, but it still takes almost twice as long as R. **The difference vs R is striking!** And it also suggests there is nothing inherently wrong with the connection to the SQL server.

**If the answer is: "no, R is much faster, period", could someone elaborate why? It would be very interesting to understand what causes the difference.**

For gigantic tables I might think of exporting them to a format like parquet or feather, get R to read them and then export to SQL for R. However, for mid-sized tables (anything between 30 and 200 MBs of data) I would much much rather find a better solution in Python.

PS It's a SQL Server Express running on the very same PC from which I am running Python and R.

### Edit

In answer to a comment, I have compared execution times with different sizes, and the ratio of R's time to pyodbc's seems fairly constant. Take it with a grain of salt - I am not a database expert, and there may well be database configurations or other factors I am missing which are playing a role. The bottom line remains that, in my cases, R is almost twice as fast.

[image]

My code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import timeit
from sqlalchemy import create_engine #, MetaData, Table, select
import pymssql
ServerName = myserver
Database = mydb
params = '?driver=SQL+Server+Native+Client+11.0'

# we define the pyodbc connection
engine_pyo = create_engine('mssql+pyodbc://' + ServerName + '/' + Database + params,
                           encoding='latin1', fast_executemany=True)
conn_pyo = engine_pyo.connect()

# now the turbodbc
engine_turbo = create_engine('mssql+turbodbc://' + ServerName + '/' + Database + params, encoding='latin1')
conn_turbo = engine_turbo.connect()

# pymssql is installed but doesn't work.
# I get:
# connect() got an unexpected keyword argument 'driver'
#engine_pyms = create_engine('mssql+pymssql://' + ServerName + '/' + Database + params, encoding='latin1')
#conn_pyms = engine_pyms.connect()

sheets = 15
rows= int(10e3)

def create_data(sheets, rows):
    df = {} # dictionary of dataframes
    for i in range(sheets):
        df[i] = pd.DataFrame(data= np.random.rand(rows,30) )
        df[i]['a'] = 'some long random text'
        df[i]['b'] = 'some more random text'
        df[i]['c'] = 'yet more text'
    return df

def data_to_sql(df, conn):
    for d in df:
        df[d].to_sql('Test ' + str(d) , conn, if_exists='replace' )

#NB: df is a dictionary containing dataframes - it is NOT a dataframe
# df[key] is a dataframe
df = create_data(sheets, rows)

rep = 1
n = 1
t_pyodbc = timeit.Timer( "data_to_sql(df, conn_pyo)" , globals=globals() ).repeat(repeat = rep, number = n)
t_turbo = timeit.Timer( "data_to_sql(df, conn_turbo)" , globals=globals() ).repeat(repeat = rep, number = n)
```

My R code:

```
library(tictoc)
library(readxl)
library(tidyverse)
library(dplyr)
library(dbplyr)
library(DBI)

tic("data creation")
rows = 10000
cols = 30
tables = 15

dataframes <- list()

for (i in 1:tables){

newdf <- as_tibble( matrix(rnorm(rows * cols),rows , cols) ) 
newdf <- mutate(newdf, a = 'some long random text') 
newdf <- mutate(newdf, b = 'some more random text') 
newdf <- mutate(newdf, c = 'yet more text')

dataframes[[i]] <- newdf

}
toc()

tic("set up odbc")
con <- DBI::dbConnect(odbc::odbc(),
                      driver = "SQL Server",
                      server = "LTS-LNWS010\\SQLEXPRESS",
                      database = "CDL",
                      trusted_connection = TRUE)
toc()

tic("SQL export")
for(i in seq_along(dataframes)){
  DBI::dbWriteTable(con, paste("Test_", i), dataframes[[i]], overwrite = TRUE)
}
toc()
```

Comment: 7 vs 4 seconds seems hardly striking, but is that just benchmark numbers and your actual workloads suffer more?

Comment: Precisely. The point is not that I am dying to save 3 seconds on a one-off basis - the point is that R is almost twice as fast, and this difference can be material in certain circumstances, where I have to write lots and lots of data to SQL many many times. That's why I was contemplating an intermediate solution of pandas -> parquet -> R -> SQL

Comment: It'd be interesting to see numbers for some bigger datasets. Does the ratio of ~2 apply to those as well?

Comment: Does mssql have something like Copy in postgres? If it has, you can convert df to in memory csv and copy it to db.

Comment: @Pythonista - pymssql doesn't use an ODBC driver so you'd need to omit `params` from your connection URL.

Comment: Thanks! It works now, but pymssql is ludicrously slow: 235 seconds when pyodbc takes 7!!!

Comment: It might not make a significant difference, but I do notice that you are using different ODBC drivers for your Python test and your R test.

Comment: Also, it might be interesting to see if there are any obvious differences reported by SQL Profiler (for the statements being executed on the server) or Wireshark (using a remote server, to see how much "stuff" is actually sent to the SQL Server instance).